# Every other row hit during For Each on DataGridViewRow with Remove

Tags: .net, vb.net, datagridview, foreach

Suppose I have a DataGridView called `gridFiles`.

```
For Each row as DataGridView in gridFiles.Rows
    MsgBox(row.Cells("somekey").Value.ToString)
    gridFiles.Rows.Remove(row)
Next
```

I will see message boxes, but only for every other row.  What I think is happening is that the internal pointer for `gridFiles.Rows` gets off, because there is 1-fewer rows on the next iteration.

I need to iterate through every row, and conditionally decide whether to delete them or not (based on the success or failure of another action).

How can I get around this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you iterate through a collection `gridFiles.Rows` and remove from that collection you disturb the collection itself and iteration doesn't work like it should (foreach attempts to get the next value, but the index has changed because of the item that has been removed) leaving you with an 'every other' evaluation.

the solution (or A solution, there are other ways to skin this) is to put the items to be removed in there own collection and the after your foreach loop, loop through the 'itemsToBeRemoved' collection and remove those items from the original collection.

Comment: :o) Magnus wrote a nice demo of what I just explained.

Comment: I'm surprised that is not throwing an exception.

Comment: No individual command in the sequence is "bad" per se. The issue is in the order of operations. If you look at the second example that Magnus offered, if you _don't_ iterate backwards, you will get an exception because `i` will outrun the actual index.

Answer (score 4):

```
dim deleteList As new List(Of DataGridViewRow)
For Each row as DataGridViewRow in gridFiles.Rows
    MsgBox(row.Cells("somekey").Value.ToString)
    deleteList.Add(row)
Next
For Each row As DataGridViewRow in deleteList 
   gridFiles.Rows.Remove(row)
Next
```

Or, itterate the collection backwards

```
For i As Integer = gridFiles.Rows.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
    MsgBox(row.Cells("somekey").Value.ToString)
    gridFiles.Rows.Remove(gridFiles.Rows(i))
End If
```